# "God bless you" equivalent for fart?

Tags: politeness, exclamations

In response to someone sneezing there are a few possible phrases you can say as a form of polite acknowledgement:

> "God bless you"
>
> "Gesundheit"

And others.

But with a fart you laugh, deride or come up with something clever to say on the spot.

Is there a commonly known polite word or phrase that says "I acknowledge your flatulence" similar to things said after sneezing?

Comment: [on hold] answer to the question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: In this case, acknowledgment constitues impoliteness. The polite thing to do is precisely not to acknowledge it. So, "I don't agree with your question."

Comment: I like "[Another county heard from.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/another_county_heard_from)" (Well, I never actually _say_ it in this instance - like most people, I pretend nothing happened - but I like to imagine myself saying it.)  I first saw this phrase in _Catch-22_, and have loved it ever since.

Comment: Agree with Talia and MT_Head - I don't think there's a way to acknowledge this politely. Better stay quiet and hold on your laughter.

Comment: If it’s *God Bless You* on one end, shouldn’t it be [*Devil Take the Hindmost*](http://www.songlyrics.com/andrew-lloyd-webber/devil-take-the-hindmost-lyrics/) on the other?

Comment: "Bless you" is for sneezes, "damn you" is for farts.

Answer (score 4):

Supposedly, Princess Diana said...

> *Oh, no, it's not dogs I don't like -- it's corgis. [**They get the blame for all the farts**.](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk%3aDiana,_Princess_of_Wales)*

So I imagine that in Buckingham Palace, if (God forbid! :) the Queen should [let one rip](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let_one_rip), the proper reaction would be to exclaim *"You naughty dog, Holly!"* (assuming you [know the dog's name](http://www.royal.gov.uk/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/20%20most%20asked%20questions.aspx)). I don't think it would be polite to say anything that explicitly blamed the Queen.

I'm not royal, and I don't have a dog. In my house, the proper reaction (from either the guilty party, or considerate others helping him/her save face) is...

> [***Bloody cat!***](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IPceEBqKmE0C&pg=PA197&dq=fart%20%22blame%20the%20cat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Wo08UvzPEemV0AWo6oDIAw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=fart%20%22blame%20the%20cat%22&f=false)

Cats are more likely than dogs to be curled up in a corner out of sight, so you can blame one even if you can't see it (at a pinch, even in a house that doesn't have cats, though that *is* stretching it a bit).

Comment: This reminds me of an old joke: a young man meets his intended's parents for the first time. After dinner, he and her father retire for brandy and cigars, but the young man has a wicked case of gas. He decides to risk a small sneaky one; the old man immediately says "Rover!" The kid says to himself "Aha! He blames the dog!" so he sneaks off another. Again: "Rover!" Relaxing now, the kid just lets one rip - whereupon the old man says "Rover! Get over here before he ****s on you!"

Comment: Princess Anne, so the story goes, was on a horse that farted loud and clear. Princess Anne said to a bystander ‘I’m sorry about that.’ The bystander said ‘Oh that’s alright. I thought it was the horse.’

Comment: You guys are cracking me up! My family used to blame the dog, or more whimsically, a mythical duck.

Comment: @Bradd: It gets worse. ["How dare you fart before the Queen!" - "I'm sorry, I didn't know it was her turn!"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WCJyTEDix9gC&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166&dq=%22how+dare+you+fart+before+the+queen%22&source=bl&ots=A5CNfchCkA&sig=wAA9W_AFJS5qIlZiwdr-EnPGHR4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qLE8UrHtEeas0QXtvYEY&ved=0CFgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22how%20dare%20you%20fart%20before%20the%20queen%22&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

My preferred retort is 'everyone's a critic!'

Answer (score 1):

### **"Ah, Bisto!"**

[image: Ah! Bisto]

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bisto&defid=510491) has an apt definition:

> **Bisto**
>
> A fart. To be used in the expression "Ah, Bisto" inferring relief at the passing of some aromatic wind.
>
> Origin: Bisto adverts. The family sit down to eat and one member of the family (following a deep inhalation through the nose) expresses their delight at the smell provided by the gravy, by exclaiming: "Ah, Bisto".
>
> *Q "Did you just let one go?"*
>
> *A "Ah, Bisto!"*
>
> by TommyE February 16, 2004

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no commonly known polite word or phrase that says "I acknowledge your flatulence" similar to things said after sneezing. Farting is usually considered too impolite to comment on.

Answer (score 0):

When I moved to the UK with my family, I noticed some people saying "**Pardon me**". Though, it's something the person who 'commits the crime' says, and not the people around him/her.